# Is it possible to format an open file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I would like to format the maven settings.xml file in ~user/.m2. Is it possible to format an open file not in a project with Eclipse?

Comment: Did you try *File > Open File...*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is possible. Either right click on the file and choose open with Eclipse or go to File -> Open file